# requests.compat error on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am running the following code in Python 3 to authenticate in Twitter:

```
import time
import tweepy

consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

When I run it I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'requests.compat'; 'requests' is not a package
```

Any idea on what I am supposed to do to fix it?

Comment: Is that your entire code?

Comment: In the future please make sure that you've also included the *Traceback* as it makes the actual error easier to debug